# MDI child form is shown behind TableLayoutPanel control

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, tablelayoutpanel

I have a borderless MDI Form witch fit screen size, I have placed on it 1 centered fixed size TableLayoutPanel control with 2 rows, at the top row (10%) I've placed a horizontal RibbonBar control, at the bottom row (90%) I placed a split container with 2 panels: the Left panel is used to host a vertical RibbonBar control and the right side is left to show child forms.
When I click to show the required child form, it loads behind the TabelLayoutPanel, I can see only a small part of it and cannot bring it to front.

I have tried to change FormBorderstyle property of both Parent and childs, also TopMost property of the childs. The issue remains the same.

Is someone having an idea on this matter, or maybe is there a better solution to layout The MDI Form ?

Comment: try giving zindex to child forms greater then tablelayoutpanel

Comment: I am using Windows Forms, how can I use Z-index ?

Comment: This is by design, the MDI child windows are parented to the dark gray MDI client window.  You must dock the panel to an edge of the MDI parent form to shrink the client window.

Comment: Every Windows Control have this method Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex please set the z-index and try again http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx

Comment: @Hans, I need to center the fixed size TableLayoutPanel in the variable size MDI (different users screens resolutions), then I have to deal with the centered remaining space of the dark gray MDI client window, so maybe docking 2 Panels at left and right sides of the dark gray window is the beginning of the solution.

Comment: @HatSoft, tried your solution and did not succeded, maybe something is missing at my side.

Comment: @Hans, Your solution is right, I think that TableLayoutPanel is not compliant with what I wanted to do, so I docked 4 panels in the MDI dark gray window, 1 Left, 1 right, 1 top, and 1 beside the left one to host vertical menu. Now I can display the child Form in the remaining space inside the dark gray window. but borderless child forms have different behavior, I'm still trying to find out the cause.

Comment: @HatSoft, please I would like you help me understand the usage of Z-index on WinForms by providing sample code or some links, I believe that this should be useful for my next steps, thank you.